# Is it possible to call a method that is both final and protected from a unit test?

Tags: scala, mockito

I have this example class

```
class Foo extends Parent {
  final override protected def test(): String = "hello world"
}
```

As it is now, I am unable to call this method directly within my unit test. I am using Mockito and from what I've read so far, I either need to

- remove the `final` so I can extend and override the access modifier (turn protected to private[package]) with another child class (Bar extends Foo)
- update the Foo class to be `private[package]`.

Neither options are desirable. Is there a way to keep the signature while still exposing the method to be unit testable?

Comment: Could you create a subclass with a different method that calls this one and call that new method from the test?

Comment: That works, not sure why I didn't think of that before. Many thanks

Comment: Feel free to add an answer to question and I'll accept it. I'm surprised this isn't a more common answer to the "how do I test a protected method" question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `test` indirectly accessible by extending `Foo` in the test with a subclass declaring a public method that calls `test`.

You didn't mention which test execution framework you're using, but here's an example using ScalaTest with the `FlatSpec` style:

```
import org.scalatest.flatspec.AnyFlatSpec

class FooSpec extends AnyFlatSpec {
  class TestingFoo extends Foo {
    def accessibleTest: String = test
  }
  it should "say hello" in {
    assert(new TestingFoo().accessibleTest == "hello world")
  }
}
```

The overall approach would be similar with other testing frameworks.